# Chrome browser is opening but url is not getting loaded with driver.get() function

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome version: Version 112.0.5615.138
Chrome driver version: ChromeDriver 112.0.5615.49
Selenium version: selenium-java-4.9.0

Source code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class OpeningBrowser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win-aarch64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver drv = new ChromeDriver();
        String str = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm";
        drv.get(str);
    }
}
```

Chrome browser should open and navigate to URL.

Answer (score 0):

You set path to the Gecko driver.
`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win-aarch64\\geckodriver.exe");`

This dirver is for the Firefox browser not for Chrome

For Chrome browser you should install and set path to the chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the gecko driver is Firefox and you are trying to start Chrome. Make sure you have the most updated Selenium 4.6+ and you no longer need to download the driver, set the driver path, etc. [DriverManager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will take care of all of that for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String url = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm";
    driver.get(url);
}
```